# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a form that will allow users to post a date idea. The form fields is content (body) and tag (category: eat, drink, listen/watch, play, explore, etc). I have it setup so user should be able to submit form from their profile, though when I view the User profile I received a: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty. It points to '<%= form_for(@letsgo) do |f| %>' from the _form.html. Also brought up is the show.html '<%= render 'letsgos/form' %>'

users_controller:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @letsgos = @user.letsgos.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

Comment: Isn't that a plural error? I `form_for(@letsgo)...` I think you missed a `s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `user_controller.rb`, the show method (where you're basically having the `letsgo` form) should initialize the `@letsgo` var.

```
def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @letsgos = @user.letsgos.paginate(page: params[:page])
   @letsgo = current_user.letsgos.build
end
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! I had that code, though mines was '    @letsgo = current_user.letsgos.build if signed_in?'. However I was using it to def something else instead of placing it under def show. Thanks for pointing it out!